# XPages Dynamic Content Control: Hash does not update when clicking browser's back button

Tags: xpages

I have a very simple XPage that contains two links and a dynamic content control.  If I click on the Page 1 link the hash is set to `#content=page1` then I click on Page 2 link and the hash is set to `#content=page2`. Now I click the browser's back button and the facet switches to page1 but the hash stays at `#content=page2` and the browser's forward button is grayed out. It looks like the URL flickers to me so it might be getting overwritten but I can't say for sure.

I am using Extension Library version 901v00_16.20160128-1014 and I have tested using Chrome and Firefox.

My XPage:

```
<xp:link escape="true" styleClass="list-group-item" text="Page 1" id="link1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" id="eventHandler2" refreshId="dynamicContent1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c = getComponent("dynamicContent1"); c.show("page1")}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>

<xp:link escape="true" styleClass="list-group-item" text="Page 2" id="link2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" id="eventHandler1" refreshId="dynamicContent1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var c = getComponent("dynamicContent1"); c.show("page2")}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>

<xe:dynamicContent id="dynamicContent1" partialEvents="true" useHash="true" defaultFacet="page1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:div id="page1" xp:key="page1">Page 1</xp:div>
        <xp:div id="page2" xp:key="page2">Page 2</xp:div>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xe:dynamicContent>
```

I have been using the Extension Library Demo database: Core_DynamicPage.xsp page as a reference and this seems to works fine in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my xsp property for "Minimum Supported Release" from "Release 9.0.1" to "Minimum release required by the XPage features used" the issue went away.